# Why should I use live data instead of Observable?

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-databinding, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I searched a lot on forums and stackoverflow but I was not able to find a satisfying answer. While observable fields work great with data binding in my view models, why should I use a Live Data object instead?

I know that Live Data is lifecycle aware and it only updates the UI in activity/fragment's active state, but is it really much better to use Live Data instead of Observable fields?
Because I am working on a finance app project and it really doesn't do much ui work with observables but it updates the ui only whenever it receives a server response which requires a user interaction.

Also when the activity is destroyed, do fragment's view model and its data still stay in memory? If not -and I suppose not - what is the advantage of live data over observables about memory leak?

Comment: To give you subjective input based on my experience with both RxJava & LiveData: I only see a real case for LiveData in databinding-based layout XML files, where it really is quite convenient. But even so my LiveData objects just wrap RxJava-based data. Everywhere else in my code it's straight RxJava, as it's far more flexible & expressive. Yet RxJava has an extremely steep learning curve, that would overwhelm many Android devs, and remains hard to use correctly for the rest, so LiveData may be a better choice for simpler needs.

Comment: @Uli I am also not an expert on RxJava, but it's still easy for me to use on simple cases. However as Commonsware pointed, it may be a good approach to use it for simpler lifecycle management, I think I will go on with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why should I use a Live Data object instead?

You do not have to use `LiveData`. It is an option, nothing more.

> I know that Live Data is lifecycle aware and it only updates the UI in activity/fragment's active state, but is it really much better to use Live Data instead of Observable fields?

You are going to have to deal with the lifecycle somehow. If you prefer to manually dispose of your Rx subscriptions, or if you want to use a library for that, you are welcome to do so. Some will prefer to wrap their Rx types in `LiveData` using `LiveDataReactiveStreams` or similar mechanisms, so they will clean up automatically based on the activity/fragment lifecycle.

Also, not everybody uses RxJava. RxJava has a substantial learning curve, and some developers would prefer to skip it. For them, just using `LiveData` directly can be useful.

> Also when the activity is destroyed, do fragment's view model and its data still stay in memory?

That depends on your implementation.

For example, suppose that by "fragment's view model", you mean that you are using the Jetpack `ViewModel` system. In that case:

- If the activity is being destroyed as part of a configuration change, all `ViewModel` objects scoped to that activity and its fragments will be retained across the configuration change
- If the activity is being destroyed because it is truly finished, all `ViewModel` objects scoped to that activity and its fragments will be garbage collected when the activity itself is garbage collected

> what is the advantage of live data over observables about memory leak?

Again, at some point, you need to `dispose()` your RxJava `Disposable` objects. Whether you do that yourself, use a library, or rely upon `LiveData` wrappers is up to you.

Comment: This is one satisfying and explanatory answer, I accept it.